# Laravel relationship custom key

Tags: laravel, relationship

I'm new in Laravel about a few weeks and now I'm currently learning Relationship task. I have been searching related topics about it but I don't have a clue why my code is not working.

I have 2 tables Employee & Phone:

**Employee:**

- ID                int
- Name          varchar
- Age             int
- Position       varchar
- Address       varchar
- created_at   timestamp
- update_at    timestamp
- deleted_at    timestamp

**Phone:**

- ID                     int
- No                    varchar
- Employee_ID   int

I'm using Laravel v.8

**Models:** PhoneS.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PhoneS extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "Phone";
 
    public function EmployeeS()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\EmployeeS', 'Employee_ID', 'ID');
    }
}
```

**Models:** EmployeeS.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EmployeeS extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "Employee";
    
    public function PhoneS()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PhoneS', 'Employee_ID', 'ID' );
    }
}
```

**Controller:** Phone.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 
 use App\Models\EmployeeS;
 
 class Employee extends Controller {
     public function index()
     {
         $EmployeeS = EmployeeS::all();
         return $EmployeeS;     
         
     }
 }
```

**The result:**

> [
>  {
>     "ID": 1,
>     "Name": "John",
>     "Age": 26,
>     "Position": "IT",
>     "Address": "Boulevard street",
>     "created_at": null,
>     "updated_at": null,
>     "deleted_at": null
> },
> {
>     "ID": 2,
>     "Name": "Doe",
>     "Age": 25,
>     "Position": "Acc",
>     "Address": "Avenue street",
>     "created_at": null,
>     "updated_at": null,
>     "deleted_at": null
> },
> ...
> ...
> ]

There's no **field: PhoneS** there...
and when I try to access it with: *return $EmployeeS->PhoneS*, it gives error message:

> Exception 
> Property [PhoneS] does not exist on this collection
> instance.

Can anyone let me know what happen? 
I believe there's something I missed about Laravel Relationship concept.
Can you pointing me where I got missed?

Thanx in advance..

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `EmployeeS::all();` to `EmployeeS::with('PhoneS')->get();`

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices), you'll have a lot less headache with unforced errors if you follow advised standard.

Comment: Amazing! Thanx @KamleshPaul & Tpojka

Answer (score 1):

`EmployeeS::all()` will return a collection of EmployeeS objects representing database records

So `$EmployeeS->PhoneS` will not work as it is like trying to access related model on a collection - hence the error you are getting

```
$EmployeeS = EmployeeS::all(); //$EmployeeS is a collection

foreach($EmployeeS as $employee) {
    //Iterating over each object in collection
    echo $employee->PhoneS //this will work
}
```

However if you are going to need the related record then it's better to eager load the relation to avoid N+1 queries issue

```php
$Employee::with('PhoneS')->all();
```

Comment: Nice... It works like a charm. Thanks!
But why when I'm using: $EmployeeS[0], there is no Phone field.
But I can access it by using: $EmployeeS[0]->Phone